# Alternative to tine20 (Calendar, Addressbook, ...)

Tags: calendar, address-book

Up to now we use [tine20](https://github.com/tine20/tine20) for our calendars and contacts.

But some things don't work and I have the feeling that there is only little progress.

The trend looks not good: https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?date=all&q=%2Fm%2F05zw1cr

Required Features:

- Shared calendars
- Addressbook
- Web GUI
- Sync to mobile devices
- self-hosting
- Open source

Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

According to this page nextcloud can do this: [nextcloud comparing itself with others](https://nextcloud.com/compare/)

- SUPPORTED GROUPWARE (CALENDAR/CONTACTS/MAIL/KANBAN)
- MOBILE CALENDAR/CONTACT INTEGRATION
- Web GUI
- Sync to mobile devices
- self-hosting
- open source